# Exclude string from if statement

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

My formula works fine in most cases, but I need to stop it from adding the asterisk if the {SAMPLEPARAM.PA_NAME} = "Methylene Chloride". How can I achieve this behavior?

```
if {METHOD.ME_TYP} ='COFA'
then '* '+ {SAMPLEPARAM.PA_NAME}
else if (IsNull ({METHOD.ME_TYP}) or {METHOD.ME_TYP} = ' ')
then {SAMPLEPARAM.PA_NAME}
else {SAMPLEPARAM.PA_NAME}
```

Comment: what is problem with formula you created?

Comment: So add an `and {SAMPLEPARAM.PA_NAME} = "Methylene Chloride"`  ?

Comment: "Methylene Chloride" is a {METHOD.ME_TYP} ='COFA' so it will put the * at the start. I want it to exclude just this one

Answer (score 0):

If you want "Methylene Chloride" to not have an asterisk, all you have to do is tell the code to skip over if it finds that specific string.

At the same time, simplify your code by removing the part when you check `{METHOD.ME_TYP}`. There are three branches in your code, but the last two are the same. The ELSE IF does nothing useful:

```
IF ({METHOD.ME_TYP} = 'COFA') AND ({SAMPLEPARAM.PA_NAME} <> "Methylene Chloride")
  THEN '* ' + {SAMPLEPARAM.PA_NAME}
ELSE {SAMPLEPARAM.PA_NAME}
```